# Is it possible to automatically make Vim vertically center the line when typing?

Tags: vim

When typing a bunch of text, the cursor gets pushed towards the bottom of the screen. I regularly have to exit INSERT mode to type `zz`, so that Vim centers the line on which my cursor resides. I would like something more automatic: for instance, if the cursor is trespassing a threshold (say 5-8 lines below "the line in the center of the screen"), Vim would `zz` directly, without to exit INSERT mode.

It may disrupt the typing process, but since I would be typing, my eyes would be staring at the screen and see that *something is happening*. I think exiting INSERT mode is more disruptive.

Is there a configuration option or a plugin supporting this use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep the cursor's line centered by setting the 'scrolloff' option to a large value:

```
set scrolloff=999
```

Description of 'scrolloff' from the help page:

```
Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
This will make some context visible around where you are working.  If
you set it to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be
in the middle of the window (except at the start or end of the file or
when long lines wrap).
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will vertical center cursor automatically when its resides within last 1/3 of buffer on typing any character or entering insert mode in this region ( add to `.vimrc`):

```
augroup autoCenter
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertCharPre,InsertEnter * if (winline() * 3 >= (winheight(0) * 2))
                                            \| norm! zz
                                        \| endif
augroup END
```

`:h autocmd-events` and add any other *event* you may need to trigger centering.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution at : https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26055/31046

This works fine for me in Insert mode :

```
inoremap <CR> <C-\><C-O><C-E><CR>
inoremap <BS> <BS><C-O>zz
inoremap <right> <right><C-O>zz
inoremap <left> <left><C-O>zz
inoremap <up> <up><C-O>zz
inoremap <down> <down><C-O>zz
```

I only need to hit either backspace or any arrow-key when in Insert mode for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

There's a more natural/easy way to achieve that, with this setting every time you enter in insert mode the screen gets vertically centered:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * norm zz
```